# How to save raster data in R object format?

Tags: r, save, raster

I don't know how to deal with `save.image()`and `saveRDS()`with raster data in R. I have understood that raster package open a connexion with the image file using `raster()` function, so it doesn't really open the file into R workspace.

I want to save my workspace (data.frame, list, raster, etc) with `save.image()`  function (or similar) and open it in a different computer. If I try to plot or process a raster object saved in a different computer, always have the same issue:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
  `C:\path\to\file.tif' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

Is there a way to save a raster object (opened as external file) in R format? I don't mean raster format as tiff nor grid and others.

Comment: You can Save As A spatialpixelsdataframe.  See Here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/111542

Comment: @lorenzo-busetto Thanks! Works perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save rasters, like other R objects, using the `save` command.

```
save(r,file="r.Rdata")
```

On a different computer, you can load that file using

```
load("r.Rdata")
```

which will bring back the raster `r` in your workspace.

I have tried this across Windows and Linux and it never gives problems

Comment: Great answer. I tried across OS X and Windows, works great!

Comment: I cam across the same issue, but I'm afraid that this has the same problem as `saveRDS()` mentioned by @aldo_tapia. For this case is not much difference between `save.image()`, `save()` and `saveRDS()` - check [article](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/01/saving-and-loading-r-objects/). They all save just the path to the raster but not the raster per se, because the raster is not loaded in RAM.

Answer (score 5):

At your own risk, you can use the `readAll` function to load the raster into memory before saving. e.g.

```
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
r <- readAll(r) # force data into memory
save(r, file = 'r.RData')
```

It can be loaded on a different machine as mentioned

```
load('r.Rdata`)
```

Beware, this will be problematic for very large rasters on memory limited systems