# Do R's raster functions returning new rasters work on-disk?

Tags: r, memory, raster, ram

R's raster functionality provides a convenient handle on a memorymapped raster on-disk, allowing the manipulation of very big datasets. The `aggregate` function, and other functions in the package, takes an input raster and creates a new raster of smaller resolution.
Does the new returned raster live in memory, or is an on-disk temporary copy created with a new memory-mapping into that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend on the raster size and the amount of RAM the computer has available. Small data sets are kept in memory, large data sets are stored on disk.

Deciding whether `x` is small or large is done with `canProcessInMemory`, using "rasterOptions", `maxmemory` and `memfrac`

```
library(raster)
x <- raster(res=1/12)
values(x) <- 1

rasterOptions()
#maxmemory     : 1e+09 
#memfrac       : 0.6 

canProcessInMemory(x, verbose=TRUE) 
#memory stats in GB
#mem available: 50.07
#        60%  : 30.04
#mem needed   : 0.28
#max allowed  : 0.93  (if available)

#[1] TRUE
```

In the example above there is 50 GB of RAM available. The maximum fraction that may be used is 0.6 times the available RAM (`0.6*50=30 GB`) or `maxmemoy`, whichever is smaller. `maxmemory` is expressed in bytes, so that is `1e+09  / 1073741824 = 0.93 GB`.

To avoid writing data to disk (which slows things down), you can set `maxmemory` to a larger number, or even to `Inf`.

```
rasterOptions(maxmemory=Inf)
```

The default for maxmemory will increase in future versions.

In version 2.8 (currently under development) there is a third criterion. If the number of cells of a Raster* is larger than (2^31 - 1; the highest integer in R), `canProcessInMemory` returns `FALSE`.

To determine whether a Raster* object `x` uses a file, you can do

```
filename(x)
#[1] ""
```

If is returns an empty string, there is no file. You can force writing to file with the `todisk` option (meant for testing purposes only)

```
y <- x * 1
filename(y)
#[1] ""

rasterOptions(todisk=TRUE)
y <- x * 1
filename(y)
#"/temp/RtmpQN2nYn/raster/r_tmp_2019-01-27_120723_22156_26708.grd"
```

If you want a file, it is best to use the `filename` argument that most methods have.

The temporary files are removed when a session ends (unless you use `rasterOptions` to set the temp folder to a different location (not recommended))

Answer (score 0):

I believe the newly created objects are stored in on-disk temporary copies but they can be "forced" into memory with `raster::readALL`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54314986/3362993